# How to update the Existing File (Path_Provider) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-file

I have a question about `path_provider` package, i'm fetching the api data and once i received the data i cache the `json` data in `File`. How can i update the existing file, Because whenever i got any changes or updates in api data then it doesn't make any update or refresh on cache file data. Is there any articles or documents or videos to show how to update the existing file?

Comment: if you found an answer, please tell us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add

```
File(path).deleteSync(recursive: true);
```

to delete the existing file then recreate it as it's a new.